# The target account name is incorrect Windows server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain, controller

I have a new server running Windows server 2012 R2 in a LAN network with a domain controller that was working with all the users and clients for about a week and a half. Then, today, when I was doing nothing in particular, it displayed an error where I couldn't access the network server shared folders, or the machine itself on the network from first one user, then the other users.

It is a small healthcare office that requires the server for some programs and I was ecstatic that it worked, until it didn't.

What I did do was install a Synology backup NAS and tried to connect it to the domain as well with a name that was the same as the office server. I think this may have caused the problem, though I had the DNS point to the server IP as all the other clients, and the connection attempts failed. I just thought I should include that because that is all that I could think that I changed.

The error I get is "The target account name is incorrect."

I tried to reset the users on the server. Nothing.

I caught on that the name could be confusing, so I reset the backup NAS name to something else. Nothing I think.

I fiddled with IP settings, nada.

I tried to unjoin the computer clients from the domain and then rejoin. Nothing.

I figured I had nothing left to lose as the info on the server is intact, it is something with communicating with the client machines. I renamed the server which is the domain controller and restarted. The clients did not connect once, then they gave me the option to connect with login credentials and I had access!!

So, I am able to limp through as I remapped some paths to use this workaround so I can see patients tomorrow and access files.

The problem, is there is no domain controller as it was demoted with the name change and cannot be accessed, which is expected. I just want to be able to understand why this happened and if the problem will be solved if I make the renamed server the domain controller by elevating it.

If I have to, I will make a whole new domain and connect the workstations and wipe the old one out, but I do not want to reinstall the server machine!!

Please advise as I spent about 7 hours trying to figure this out and don't want to make any changes without knowing why because I am the IT person for the practice, and it was working perfectly.

Comment: Also, I could access the shared folder and the server by directly going through the IP of the server and could see and access all the contents that way. However, that won't do anything good for my server based programs on the clients who read the authentication keys on the server.